# Connect to informix with python's ibm_db

Tags: python, database-connection, informix

I'm pretty new to python. I'm trying to connect to an informix server using python and ibm_db.connect(). However I can't seem to succeed and the error messages don't help.

Using java and jdbc I can connect successfully with the following connection url:

jdbc:informix-sqli://10.20.30.40:1234/mydb:INFORMIXSERVER=foo_bar;USER=user;PASSWORD=pass;

My attempt at using ibm_db is:

```
ibm_db.connect('HOSTNAME=10.20.30.40;PORT=1234;DATABASE=mydb;PROTOCOL=ONSOCTCP;UID=user;PASSWORD=pass;', '', '')
```

But it gives an error (Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL0902C  A system error occurred. Subsequent SQL statements cannot be processed. IBM software support reason code: "".  SQLSTATE=58005)

I would like if possible an equivalent string I can put in as the first argument to

```
ibm_db.connect('', '', '')
```

So I can connect with python.

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://code.google.com/p/ibm-db/issues/detail?id=116&can=1&q=ONSOCTCP, This might be helpful for you. If you still facing issue then you can post your query to https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ibm_db for quick response.

Answer (score 0):

Protocol onsoctcp is not supported by ibm_db.

Please check https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0207.htm, This can help you to configure a DDRA (tcpip) access to your database.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue with ibm_db and now I use jayDeBeApi to connect to Informix through python. it requires java JDBC driver and application is work like a charm.

[https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/#:~:text=The%20JayDeBeApi%20module%20allows%20you,of%20the%20Java%20JDBC%20driver](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/#:%7E:text=The%20JayDeBeApi%20module%20allows%20you,of%20the%20Java%20JDBC%20driver).

Answer (score 0):

Your JDBC connection string points to a SQLI Informix listener, but the 'ibm_db' python module uses DRDA (IBM Data Server Driver) to connect to the Informix engine.

Informix allows both SQLI and DRDA clients (and others like MongoDB). SQLI is the 'native' Informix protocol and supports all the Informix server features and data types. DRDA is what other IBM databases use (like DB2). It does have some limitations in terms of what types you can use.

You have two options:
Configure the Informix server to listen for DRDA connections in a another port (basically, create an DBALIASES using 'drsoctcp') as described here:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_11.50.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_0207.htm

Or leave the server as it is, and use a different Python module, one that uses SQLI like 'IfxPy'

https://github.com/OpenInformix/IfxPy