Trying to connect to Informix db with Python + Ibm-db
I am trying to access my Informix database with Python via the ibm_db module.
I am running with:

Python 3.12 64bits locally
Windows 11 Home

Here my code so far:
import os

# apparently I need to add the clipdriver dll before importing ibm_db
os.add_dll_directory('path_to_clidriver')
import ibm_db

cnx_string = 'DATABASE=database_name;HOSTNAME=hostname.com;PORT=9088;PROTOCOL=tcpip;UID=user;PWD=123;'

try:
    conn = ibm_db.connect(cnx_string, "", "")
    print("Connected successfully!")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Unable to connect: {e}")
    exit()

ibm_db.close(conn)

And here is the error message I get retuned:
Unable to connect: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "119.82.149.212".  Communication function detecting the error: "recv".  Protocol specific error code(s): "*", "*", "0".  SQLSTATE=08001  SQLCODE=-30081
PS G:\My Drive\Python\ibm-db> 


Which protocol does the server offer? See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63879957

@data_henrik It may be ONSOCTCP, although most of the sample code I found out there are using TCPIP

The Informix server has to be configured to offer the DRDA protocol ,which allows the clidriver used by python imb_db to operate .
Your MS Windows device (or whatever environment runs your python script) also has to have the specified port number (i.e. the number used in your connection-string for PORT=xxxxx) to be opened for inbound and outbound TCP traffic in its software firewall.
And between that environment (that's trying to connect to the database from python) and the Informix-server,  any hardware/software firewalls along the route must allow TCP traffic on this port, in both directions also.

which port number do I need to open on my Windows? and what about if the script is deployed in a Google Cloud Function?
